# Web Api and & EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, web-services, post, concurrency, asp.net-web-api2

I have three successives calls to the same web service to post some comments.
The structure is : {Doc_No is TEXT, Line_No is NUMBER, Description is TEXT}

```
Comments_doc = [{
   Doc_No: 'xx_01',
   Description : 'TOTO_1'
},
{
   Doc_No: 'xx_01',
   Description : 'TOTO_2'
},
{
   Doc_No: 'xx_01',
   Description : 'TOTO_3'
}]

$.each(Comments_doc, function(aComment){
   $.post(...) //here post aComment
});
```

The primary keys are : Doc_No and Line_No

Line_No is calculated by the web service, it looks for the last one and add one.

The problem is ; looking for the last record is faster than the insert, so at any given time, I have the same Line_No for two differents records !
How could I avoid this ?

thank you for your help.